# Handle trailing slash with Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, trailing-slash

I have a database of articles with the urls as follow:

`person/albert-einstein/` (trailing slash)

`person/albert-einstein/1` (no trailing slash)

And I was wondering what was the best way to handle url trailing slashes in Codeigniter 3?

This is what I have done/test so far:

```
echo site_url('person/albert-einstein/'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein                              
echo base_url('person/albert-einstein/'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein                              
echo site_url('person/albert-einstein/1'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein/1                 
echo base_url('person/albert-einstein/1'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein/1
```

Then I edited `config.php` to set:

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '/';
```

and printed again the urls:

```
echo site_url('person/albert-einstein/'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein/                              
echo base_url('person/albert-einstein/'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein                              
echo site_url('person/albert-einstein/1'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein/1/            
echo base_url('person/albert-einstein/1'); # http://localhost/person/albert-einstein/1
```

Now I can select `site_url()` or `base_url()` to print the url with trailing slash or without it. But now on my views I have to be very careful to which one I use and I'd rather use a function that respects the url I pass and return it with trailing slash if it have or don't add one if it doesn't have it.

And yes, I can definitely extend the helper and write a function like: `print_url()` that does what I want but I wanted to see if there's something I'm missing here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache rewite rule for forcing trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

For removing trailing slash you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

I used this [good base](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess) of `.htaccess` snippets.

Comment: Thank you for your interest on my question but remember that I use `urls`  **with** trailing slash and **without** trailing slash for different sections of my site. So your solution using `mod_rewrite` doesn't really apply to this question my friend. :-)

Comment: I followed this request: "and I'd rather use a function that respects the url I pass and return it with trailing slash if it have or don't add one if it doesn't have it". First snippet allows it.